# Finding Groups and Subgroups Such That Some Relations (and Homomorphism) Hold

Tags: group-theory

Find groups $G$ and $G'$ and a homomorphism $f : G \to G'$ so that there are subgroups $U_1, U_2 \leq G$ (with $U_1 \neq U_2$) and $U'_1, U'_2 \leq G'$ for which following diagram is true.

[image]

In particular, this means that

- $f(U_2) = U'_1 = f(U_1)$;
- $f^{-1} (U'_1) = U_2 = f^{-1}(U'_2)$; and
- there is no subgroup $U_3 \leq G$ so that $f(U_3)=U'_2.$

---

I thought about $f:(\mathbb{Z}, +)\rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}, +)$ with $x \mapsto 2x$ (which is a homomorphism).

Then, I chose $U_1=(\mathbb{Z}_e,+)=U'_1,$ which is the subgroup of even integers, $U_2=(\mathbb{Z},+)=U'_2,$ which is clearly the (trivial) subgroup of all integers.

Since the function only maps to even numbers, there is no subgroup $U \leq G$ so that $f(U)=U'_2$.

And since the inverse image of the odd numbers has no element, it follows that $f^{-1} (U'_1) = U_2 = f^{-1}(U'_2)$

Lastly, $f(U_1) \overset{!}{=} U'_1,$ but I'm not too sure about that since I would need all the odd numbers to truly map to every element of $U'_1.$

---

Could anyone give me a hint how to resolve the last problem or give me a better example?

Comment: I have withdrawn my comment! But does your example work if you define $U_1$ to be all integers rather than just the even integers?

Comment: @DerekHolt I don't think so... because then $f(U'_1)=U_1$ but that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: But in your problem statement you have said that you do want $f(U_1') = U_1$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Oh sorry, I meant to write $f^{-1}(U'_1)=U_1$

Comment: @DerekHolt Like drawn in the diagramm.

Comment: You need to be more careful to get details correct.

Comment: @DerekHolt yeah but in my question I wrote it right so thankfully no big mistake.

Comment: @Quotenbanane Clearly, you also need $U_1 \ne U_2$, right? You've not stated it, but without that assumption there's nothing stopping you from taking $U_1 = U_2$ in your own example (plus, even mentioning $U_1$ in the statement would be pointless). So please add that to your question.

Comment: @M.Vinay They don't need to be different. But why would we choose $U_1 = U_2$ if we want $f^{-1}(U'_1) = U_2$ but not $f^{-1}(U'_1) = U_1$

Comment: @Quotenbanane Well, you've not specified $f^{-1}(U_1') \ne U_1$ either. You've only stated that $f^{-1}(U_1') = U_2$, which in itself does not imply the former, unless you explicitly specify $U_1 \ne U_2$.

Comment: @M.Vinay You're right. I'll specify it immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $G = \mathbb Z_{12}$ and $G' = \mathbb Z_{18}$.

Define $f \colon G \to G'$ by $f(1_G) = 6_{G'}$ (and extend).
Then $f$ is a homomorphism with $\operatorname{im} f = \langle 6_{G'} \rangle = \{0, 6, 12\}$.

Let $U_2' = G' = \mathbb Z_{18}$, $U_2 = G = \mathbb Z_{12}$. Note that $f^{-1}(U_2') = U_2$.
But $f$ is not surjective, so $\not\exists U_3 \le G$ such that $f(U_3) = U_2'$.

Let $U_1 = \langle 2_G \rangle = \{0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10\} \le \mathbb Z_{12}$.
Let $U_1' = \langle 6_{G'} \rangle = \{0, 6, 12\} \le \mathbb Z_{18}$.

Note that $f(U_2) = \operatorname{im} f = U_1'$.
But also, $f(U_1) = \{f(0), f(2), f(4), f(6), f(8), f(10)\} = \{0, 12, 6, 0, 12, 6\} = \{0, 6, 12\} = U_1'$.